# Can we conserve angular momentum in pure translation motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

suppose a block is moving on a surface with velocity v paraller to the surface. the surface is rough and is exerting some frictional force on block.

[image: FBD]

consider the point 'O' in above image. since net Torque about 'O' is 0 so angular momentum about O must be conserved.

suppose h is the height of center of mass from ground, then
$$mhv = mhv_{final}$$
$$\implies v_{final} = v$$

**clearly this is not possible.**

I have done this many times in impure rolling motions, but why is it not applicable here?
is there any other force working on block or is the angular momentum of block something different than $mhv$ in this case

Comment: The friction force is considered to be acting on centre of mass which is at height $h$ above $O$ . So there is a net **non-zero** torque .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frictional force is not through the centre of mass of the body, so it applies a torque to the body (defined around its centre of mass). If it was a cylinder rather than a block, it would start rolling. To prevent it rotating, the normal force must apply a counter-torque. Gravity acts through the centre of mass, so the line of action of the normal force must be offset to the right, compared to your diagram. There's more pressure on the front edge of the block than the back edge. You should be able to work out how far to the right the net normal force has moved by using the constraint that the block doesn't roll over, and taking moments about the centre of mass. Then taking moments about your point $O$ we find that the torque is now non-zero - $N$ and $mg$ are equal in magnitude but at different distances from $O$ - and so the angular momentum about $O$ is not conserved. The torque is counter-clockwise, so the motion to the right slows down.

In case my mentioning the possibility of a rolling cylinder made you wonder, in this situation the normal force and gravity have to be through the point of contact, and so none of the external forces $N$, $mg$ and $F$ can contribute any torque about $O$. However, this time, the angular momentum shifts from that associated with linear motion of a cylinder sliding along the surface to rotation of the cylinder rolling along the surface.

I should add, it is common to teach students to convert any off-centre forces on a body to a force through the centre of gravity combined with a couple (a torque with no net force). It's mathematically equivalent, and allows you to balance forces and couples separately. However, it's not as clear when trying to understand intuitively what is going on, and in cases like this could potentially be misleading.

In this case, you want to understand what is going on when you take moments about $O$. Treating all the forces as force-couples through the centre of gravity enables you to calculate the dynamics, but now you have to translate both the force and the couple to a new centre to get a new force-couple, which complicates matters.

Secondly, consider what happens if the frictional force is large enough that when you try to offset the normal force $N$ to the right, it moves it outside the base of the block. It is now no longer possible for the normal force to apply enough torque to stop the block rolling over. The back edge lifts, and the block starts rolling and tumbling. If you blindly use the force-couple method without checking that the requisite normal force can actually be applied, you would miss this possibility. So I find it safer to always first consider the problem using forces along their actual lines of action. Once it has been confirmed that this picture makes sense, you can convert them all to force-couple combinations about whatever common centre is most convenient. Usually that would be the centre of mass, but not always.

Sometimes, the geometry of the shape matters, because forces have to be applied off-centre through actual points of contact, or have to be non-negative or subject to other constraints. The centre-of-mass force-couple method ignores the geometry, so there is a risk of missing toppling, rolling, lifting, string-slackening, or collapsing solutions.

Comment: Yes you are right. The normal will shift forward.

Answer (score 1):

### Title

Answering the question in the title: yes, it's possible to have constant angular momentum in a pure translation motion. Assuming we're talking about a rigid body, computing the angular momentum w.r.t. to a pole $H$ fixed in space, the equation of motion for rotation reads

$\dfrac{d \mathbf{\Gamma}_H}{dt} = - \underbrace{\mathbf{\dot{x}}_H}_{=\mathbf{0}} \times \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{M}^e_H =  \mathbf{M}^e_H$

where

- $\mathbf{\Gamma}_H = \mathbb{I}_G \cdot \mathbf{\omega} + (\mathbf{x}_G - \mathbf{x}_H) \times \mathbf{Q}$ is the angular momentum of the system w.r.t. pole $H$ located in $\mathbf{x}_H$,
- $\mathbb{I}_G$ is the inertia tensor of the system w.r.t. to its center of mass $G$, whose position in space is identified by the vector $\mathbf{x}_G$
- $\mathbf{\omega}$ is the angular velocity of the system
- $\mathbf{Q}$ is the momentum of the system
- $\mathbf{M}^e_H$ is the resultant of the external moments w.r.t. $H$ acting on the system.

With the further assumptions of $\mathbf{M}^e_H = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{\omega} = \mathbf{0}$ (pure translation), the equation of motion becomes

$\mathbf{0} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left[ (\mathbf{x}_G - \mathbf{x}_H) \times \mathbf{Q} \right] = \underbrace{(\mathbf{v}_G - \underbrace{\mathbf{\dot{x}_H}}_{= \mathbf{0}}) \times \mathbf{Q}}_{= \mathbf{0} \, \text{since $\mathbf{v}_G$ // $\mathbf{Q}$ }} + (\mathbf{x}_G - \mathbf{x}_H)\times  \dfrac{d  \mathbf{Q}}{dt}$

This last condition $(\mathbf{x}_G - \mathbf{x}_H)\times  \frac{d  \mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \mathbf{0}$ is satisfied with one of the following condition:

- the momentum of the system is constant, and thus $\frac{d  \mathbf{Q}}{dt}= \mathbf{0}$. The Second Principle of Dynamics implies that the resultant of the external force acting on the system is null.
- the time derivative of the momentum $\frac{d  \mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \frac{d (m \mathbf{v}_G)}{dt} $ (and if the mass is constant, the acceleration of the center of mass) is aligned with the vector $(\mathbf{x}_G - \mathbf{x}_H)$ joining the pole with the center of mass

### Exercise

About the exercise, there is a flaw in your force diagram. While:

- it's easy to model the resultant force of the external force $\mathbf{F}$,
- it's easy to reduce mass forces to total weight of the body and apply it to the center of mass of the block
- you're right if you write the resultant of friction between the block and horizontal surface as an horizontal force, and you identify the line of action of this force as the horizontal surface

**you're making a mistake** when you reduces the **normal reaction** of the horizontal surface to a vertical force **applied in the center of mass**. Your force diagram is not consistent with the kinematics if no rotation of the block occurs (in a problem, it may be an assumption of the problem , in real life you have to grant it): in order to satisfy the kinematic condition, the application line of the resultant force of the normal reaction must lie to the right w.r.t. the center of mass.

Physically, you don't know the very detail of the normal reaction distribution along the contact surface but, from the kinematics you see, you know that the normal reaction must be stronger on the forward region of the block so that the line of action of the force lies before (on the right) of the center of mass.

An equivalent effect can be obtained placing the normal reaction in the center of mass, but adding the equivalent moment w.r.t. the center of mass generated by reaction distribution. If you place $N$ in the center of mass, without adding this moment, you get the same inconsistent (with the physics you observe or the problem you have to solve) you would get with a uniform distribution of the normal reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a simple answer to the question in the title.

Yes. It is possible to conserve angular momentum in pure translations. The obvious example is a uniform rectilinear motion. If one uses any point lying or not on the line of motion, it is trivial to check the conservation of angular momentum with respect to that arbitrary point.

In the case of the example of the block with friction, one has to remember that when dealing with solid bodies, it is necessary to rewrite the forces as a force acting on the center of mass plus a torque.

In particular, the friction force acts on the bottom surface of the block. We have to introduce a pair of equal and opposite forces equal to the friction force but applied to the center of mass. This way, we can easily identify a force equal to the friction, acting on the center of mass, plus a torque due to two opposite forces, independent of the choice of the origin point.